# How to clone all git bitbucket repositories with a single script

Tags: git, bash, rest, bitbucket

How can I checkout all the git bitbucket repositories for a team using a bash script?

There are other questions for this topic however the bitbucket api mentioned in those answers does not exist anymore.

Comment: Iterate through the list of project names in a bash script for instance and run git clone in each one of them. You will end up with all projects cloned in the working directory.

Comment: check the bitbucket official doc and get latest api endpoints, use them for your bash script - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following script will clone all repositories of a project:

```
for r in $(curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos | jq --raw-output '.values[].links.clone[].href')
do
    git clone $r
done
```

Comment: Worked.
You may need install jq to run this script, apt-get install jq may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following script is working well to download all repositories from Bitbucket.

1. UserName not email
2. Create App-password from Bitbucket
3. Run the script by         sh script.sh

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    user=username:password

    curl -u $user 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user/permissions/teams?pagelen=100' > teams.json

    jq -r '.values[] | .team.username' teams.json > teams.txt

    for team in `cat teams.txt`
    do
      echo $team

      rm -rf "${team}"

      mkdir "${team}"

      cd "${team}"

      url="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${team}?pagelen=100"

      echo $url

      curl -u $user $url > repoinfo.json

      jq -r '.values[] | .links.clone[0].href' repoinfo.json > repos.txt

      for repo in `cat repos.txt`
      do
        echo "Cloning" $repo
        git clone $repo
      done

      cd ..

    done
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this [small project](https://github.com/ngeor/clone-all) in nodeJS,  which supports GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple script available here: https://github.com/mimo84/cloner
It works similarly to the answer from Marcelo, however it uses the api on bitbucket to fetch them.
It has jq as dependency as well.